# Entity Framework: Unable to create a constant value of type **. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this query:

```
     public override IEnumerable<Order> ExecuteQuery(MovieRentalContext database)
    {

        return from order in database.Orders
            where (customer == null || customer.Id == order.CustomerId)
            select order;
    }
```

where customer is field in the class.
There is Order class

```
   public class Order: Entity
{
    [Required]
    public Copy Copy { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EstimatedReturnDate { get; set; }
    public Salesman Salesman { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ActualReturnDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Entity contains Id. I want to get orders of a customer, but during execution the query a exception is thrown:

> Unable to create a constant value of type    >'MovieRental.DataAccess.Models.Customer'. Only primitive types or enumeration     >types are supported in this context.

I tried everything I found but it stil doesn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: What the InnerException say? Go to hte details of the exception.

Comment: What is your `customer` variable? where is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your `customer == null` code is causing this. EF is trying to convert this to SQL but customer is not in that context. Try and take that condition outside of the query.

ie

```
public override IEnumerable<Order> ExecuteQuery(MovieRentalContext database)
{
    if (customer != null)
    {
        return from order in database.Orders
            where order.CustomerId == customer.Id
            select order;
    }
    else
    {
        return from order in database.Orders
            select order;
    }

}
```

Comment: The purpose of this question is not about fixing NullReferenceException

Comment: @CodeNotFound - I think not. Not sure myself so I din't post an answer but by similar question it seems this answer is correct (again, as much as my knowledge)

Comment: @Mladen Mihajlovic - You can improve it by assigning the query of the `else` to variable, and then have an `if` statement to check the customer. in the scope of the `if` to add the `where` and eventually return

Comment: Ah :) You're right @GiladGreen. I was think Join between Customer and Order entities. it seems like Customer is not an entity. So this answer may be the correct answer.

Comment: @GiladGreen Personally I think the whole method is not well written. Anybody looking at the method called ExecuteQuery would not know it's using customer (a field outside it's scope). This should probably be 2 separate method - GetAllOrders() and GetCustomerOrders(Customer c). But I was just trying to explain his immediate problem.

Comment: @MladenMihajlovic - that is your decision :) I'm just recommending

Comment: @GiladGreen for sure  - thanks for the suggestion :)